# Proper way to debug SVN+SSH checkout over VPN failure? How to compare with a working setup?

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn, vpn, svn-checkout

**In brief**

Given a setup where SVN+SSH checkout over VPN is not working, and another where it is working, what is the correct procedure to find out what is the difference between two systems?

**Details**

I am using a 64-bit system running Windows 7. I have Open VPN and Tortoise SVN 64-bit installed.

The repository is in a remote system, and we connect using VPN.

Continuing from my earlier question  [SVN+SSH checkout over VPN using tortoise SVN, Smartsvn failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327364/svnssh-checkout-over-vpn-using-tortoise-svn-smartsvn-failing)

One new teammate (working on exactly a system, 64-bit running windows 7, same as me) has successfully checked out from the remote server (connected via Open VPN). Both of us have followed the **same steps -**

- Added some project specific Open VPN config files inside the config folder of the Open VPN installation path. Took these files from working setup of other team members.
- Initiated Open VPN connection using a user.
- ran Putty's Pageant.exe, selected the .ppk file and entered the pass phrase.

After his checkout was successful, I did a fresh installation of the softwares (OpenVPN, tortoiseSVN) using exactly the same ones he has used but still getting the following error when trying to checkout or using repository browser.

[image]

Error reads -

```
To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

But there is no such `-q` in the config file. Please read my prev question [SVN+SSH checkout over VPN using tortoise SVN, Smartsvn failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327364/svnssh-checkout-over-vpn-using-tortoise-svn-smartsvn-failing) to see what are the contents there.

I have verified that my windows firewall settings are exactly the same as his. But, there must be some difference between his system and mine. Here is a screenshot -

[image]

*Note -* He did not do any conversion of keys, just copied the contents inside Open VPN's config folder, like I did. I tried with the same files he used.

My question is what is the correct way to proceed from here?

Thanks